# "current husband"?

Tags: words, kanji, readings

How does one read **今夫**, as in the sentence here:

> 私【わたくし】の知【し】り合【あ】いの女性【じょせい】は、[5]{ご}階【かい】に元夫【もとおっと】、[10]{じゅっ}階【かい】に今夫【いまおっと】さんがいるそうで、[4]{よん}階【かい】で本人【ほんにん】がモリモリ働【はたら】いています ([source](https://otekomachi.yomiuri.co.jp/advice/20211104-OKT8T313951/?utm_source=yomiuri&utm_medium=yol&utm_campaign=yoltop_otekomachi))
>
> *I know a woman who has an ex-husband on the 5th floor and a current husband on the 10th floor, and she is working on the 4th floor.*

Is it at all conceivable that it could be pronounced 今夫【こんぶ】?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The sentence you provided shows furigana.  And it shows a reading of いまおっと.  In the linked page, I don't see any furigana.  So, first, why don't you trust the furigana?  Second, how did you get the furigana?

Comment: I don't know for certain (since I've never heard 今夫 instead of 現夫), but [this](https://yomikatawa.com/kanji/%E4%BB%8A%E5%A4%AB) website says that 今夫 read as いまお, so, both いまおっと and こんぷ is wrong, according to that website. Still, I doubt that this is the actual reading, since this looks like someone's name (that page's categorized as 苗字(surname) and 名前(first name) ), not a word...

Comment: I get the furigana from 1) j-talk.com, where it is automatically generated by a computer, which often makes mistakes, and 2) adding other readings I find in various online dictionaries, such as jisho.org, wwwjdic, and https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/en/

Comment: This is mostly like a nonce word made up at that moment. Because they just said 元夫 "ex-husband" in the previous sentence, they felt like making it symmetrical by another word 今夫 "now-husband".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the source of your doubt is that the reading いまおっと certainly is not standard. It is used by extension of colloquial [[今彼]{いまかれ}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BB%8A%E5%BD%BC/) = current boyfriend. But I don't think people usually say [今妻]{いまつま} (though [元妻]{もとつま} sounds usual).

As such こんぷ is not possible; Most 今 has the single reading depending on the combination. Words like 今日 = きょう, こんにち are exceptions (I don't come up with any other..).

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you meant by “*Most 今 has the single reading depending on the combination*.”

Comment: I meant if 今 appears in a word (written in kanji), there is usually no ambiguity on how it is read.